# Bluetooth connection in android 2.2

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using android 2.2, i tried the below code for sending the data in android

```
BluetoothDevice device=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(MACID);
Method m=device.getClass.getMethod("createRFcommSocket",new Class[]{int.class};
BluetoothSocket socket=(BluetoothSocket)m.invock(device,1);
socket.connect();
OutputStream os;
os=socket.getOutputStream();
os.write("hai".getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
socket.close();
```

Find the below error :

```
ERROR : java.io.IOException:Connection refused
```

Kindly help me in this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Yes, i added still it's coming

Comment: Magakahn Thanks, do i need to pair the device. Do you have any idea about that.

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent("android.bluetooth.device.PAIRING_REQUEST");   intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE",device);   int bluepin=1234; intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT",bluepin); sendBroadcast(intent);   error : java.lang.securityException: permission denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST

Comment: i set the above two permissions but still it throws the error. do i have add anyother permmission for this.

Comment: i am trying in android 'samsung galaxy y'. I am able to send the data when the device is already paired. But for new mobile it shows this error... Any one have any idea about this. please help.